# Accidentally created a /usr folder in my downloads. Can I delete it?

Tags: firefox, 23.04, mozilla

I was installing firefox from builds following this tutorial:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux

and when downloading one of the files from from github I did
`wget [url] -P /usr/local/share/applications`
Instead of putting it in my applications folder (which I am now realizing I don't actually have) I guess it just created that folder in my downloads folder. Now i have a folder `~/Downloads/usr/local/share/applications` and it has a lock on it because I guess I made it owned by root instead of me. Am i good to delete it since its not the same as my normal `/usr` file or will it mess things up?

Using ubuntu 23.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change ownership of all files and directories in that subtree to yourself:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo chown -R $USER usr
```

Now you can inspect that complete `~/Downloads/usr` subtree and delete it when you are sure that there is nothing in there that you want to keep:

```
rm -rf ~/Downloads/usr
```

(or use a graphical file manager of your choice)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are good to delete it. It is not a system directory.